# Why did Kaiba tear up Blue-Eyes White Dragon card in first episode of Yu-Gi-Oh!?

Tags: plot-explanation, yu-gi-oh

In the first episode of *Yu-Gi-Oh!* we see Kaiba tear up a rare Blue-Eyes White Dragon card.
He has 3 of those cards, and they are very rare so why tare up a 4th one when he could have it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules of Yu-gi-oh limit the number of copies of a single card in your deck to three, so the fourth Blue Eyes card wouldn't be useful to him. And since it's (supposedly) such a powerful card, he destroyed it so no one else could play it against him.

Of course, just storing it away somewhere would also keep others from playing it against him. But that wouldn't have been nearly as emotionally painful for Yugi. Kaiba's kind of an asshole like that.